# C# Copy TextBox and the settings i've used copy aswel

Tags: c#, textbox, copy, save, settings

Basically, I have around 40 textBoxes on a form, which I want to copy, the settings are on the first boxes I have, but I copied the first row and the save settings I used did not copy, so only the first row of boxes save the text. The code is:

```
textBox1.Text = WindowsFormsApplication12.Properties.Settings.Default.Method.ToString();
textBox2.Text = WindowsFormsApplication12.Properties.Settings.Default.Price.ToString();
textBox3.Text = WindowsFormsApplication12.Properties.Settings.Default.PerHour.ToString();
textBox4.Text = WindowsFormsApplication12.Properties.Settings.Default.Viable;

try
{
   WindowsFormsApplication12.Properties.Settings.Default.Method = textBox1.Text;
   WindowsFormsApplication12.Properties.Settings.Default.PerHour = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
   WindowsFormsApplication12.Properties.Settings.Default.Total = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
   WindowsFormsApplication12.Properties.Settings.Default.Viable = textBox40.Text;
   WindowsFormsApplication12.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error : Make sure you have only entered numbers! \n\n" + ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: So, your question is how do you copy all the data in all the text boxes...?  Also, this is a _horrible_ approach to your problem.  I would consider a control array and a foreach loop over this.  Or, just to beat HighCore to the punch, a better medium like `WPF`.

Comment: Sorry, i may of been unclear, i have SO many text boxes as you can see http://puu.sh/4Qebw.png - I want the settings above aswell as int result_1;
            int result_2;
            if (Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out result_1)
                 && Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out result_2))
            {
                textBox4.Text = (result_1 * result_2).ToString();
            } to copy too  all of them.

Comment: I understand your question... but, I don't think you are getting mine.  Do all the textboxes _always_ have data in them?

Comment: Oh my bad, im sorry. Well it depends if the user puts any in

Comment: What you are trying to do here is **very** complicated since you don't know if they will always have data, are performing calculations on said data and don't have a mechanism in-place to check if there _is data_ in any or all of the fields.

Comment: so it would just be a case of copying out the code for every textBox?